# Fullscreen in React Native Modal Selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

Currently, I am using react-native-modal-selector library. The question is when it is displaying it is not showing fullscreen mode? Instead, it showing like this in this screenshot. Two-button at the bottom and on the top some text edges are seen. [image]

I tried to change style and overstyle props. Still fullscreen is not working

**My Modal Selector**

```
<ModalSelector
           data={states}
           initValue="Select something yummy!"
           keyExtractor= {item => item.id}
           labelExtractor= {item => item.nameRu}
           style={styles.modalSelectorMain}
           overlayStyle={styles.modalSelector}/>
```

**My styles:**

```
  modalSelector: {
          height: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
  modalSelectorMain:{
      flex:1,
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set its a height to screen height.

```
 modalSelectorMain:{
      flex:1,
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
```